# JQuery simple animation not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I've been trying to create a simple animation using jQuery, only problem is, not matter what I've tried, it never seems to work. All I'm trying to do is create a Show/Hide button that Shows then Hides one sentence. I only started learning jQuery two days ago, so there's probably a simple mistake.

Here's my code:

```
<body>
    <input type="button" value="Hide" id="toggle_message" />
    <p id="message">You can see this</p>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="JQuery\jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="JQuery\toggle.js"></script>
</body>
```

From this, you can see that I have imported the jQuery library from my computer, and have tried to use a second script that has the Show/Hide code.

Here's that too:

```
$('toggle_message').click(function() {
  var value = $('#toggle_message').attr('value');
  $('message').toggle('fast');

  if (value == 'Hide') {
    $('toggle_message').attr('value', 'Show');
  } else if (value == 'Show') {
    $('toggle_message').attr('value', 'Hide');
  }
});
```

Even when saved as a .js file, no text seems to change colour like in HTML. Can someone please clarify if this is/isn't supposed to happen. I'm using Notepad++ at the moment, if that helps.

Comment: `$("toggle_message")` should be `$("#toggle_message")` to get an element by its ID, and the same for message`.

Comment: Also, jQuery has a [`.val()` function](http://api.jquery.com/val/) that is quite convenient.

Answer (score 2):

Your selector syntax is slightly wrong, and you can simplify your code somewhat.

```
$('#toggle_message').click(function() {
  $('#message').toggle('fast');

  if ($(this).val() == 'Hide') {
    $(this).val('Show');
  } else {
    $(this).val('Hide');
  }
}
```

Selectors in jQuery typically use `#` when selecting by id, or `.` when selecting by class.

Inside your function, because it's being called on your `#toggle_message` element, you can simply reference it as `$(this)`.

Answer (score 0):

Your selectors are incorrect. jQuery uses CSS style selectors, so you will need to do things like "#toggle_message" and "#message" when trying to use items with an id attribute.

Answer (score 0):

This is the code you need as already stated the only problem is the absence of the `#` when referencing `ids`

```
$('#toggle_message').click(function() {
    var value = $('#toggle_message').attr('value');
    $('#message').toggle('fast');

    if (value == 'Hide') {
        $('#toggle_message').attr('value', 'Show');
    } else if (value == 'Show') {
        $('#toggle_message').attr('value', 'Hide');
    }
 });
```